# Messed up the encoding

Tags: php

Hello I did a mistake by setting UTF8 on a website that was on ISO, the data came in the database like this `ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½2012å¹´4ï¿½19ï¿½ï¿½(ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½)` Is there any solution to get the meaning of this sentence ? it it Chinese characters normally.

Thank you.

Comment: It was `锟斤拷锟斤拷锟2012骞4锟19锟斤拷(锟斤拷锟)`. ISO-8859-1 -> GB2313

Comment: Thank you very much, but the sentence doesn't have any meaning, I think it's screwed :-(

Comment: re-coding to `utf-8` gets even more messy text.

Comment: Here it is: `\0\0\0\0\02012年4\019\0\0(\0\0\0)`. `年` means "year", but every other char is lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try changing encoding to binary, and then to iso (but do make a backup)

```
ALTER TABLE `yourtablename` CHANGE `fieldname` `fieldname` TEXT CHARACTER SET BINARY NULL ; 
ALTER TABLE `yourtablename` CHANGE `fieldname` `fieldname` TEXT CHARACTER SET latin1 NULL ;
```

or to utf..

```
ALTER TABLE `yourtablename` CHANGE `fieldname` `fieldname` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NULL ;
```